# Error Message: RStudio R Session has stopped working

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I found questions with similar title but not the same question (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200671597--Rstudio-exe-has-stopped-working-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-of-crashing?locale=en-us). I am getting the error message when I am actually running a script. The script includes few packages(data.table, rJava, XLConnect, chron, R.utils) and couple of functions. The purpose of the script is to read through about 2.3 million records in chunks of 50000 lines using "fread", do manipulations/calculations and write out. In the first attempt the script worked and went through the entire file and did not give any error except while reaching the end of the last chunk as it was attempting to read 50000 lines but found 37000 lines. It took around 7 minutes to run through the script. Since that attempt, the R-studio session keeps on crashing at different iterations in the for loop, generally between 13th and 33rd iteration of the for loop (In all there are 46 iterations). Below is a portion of the log file. What's weird is that the log file indicates different errors at different times. I'd really appreciate some help in this regard.

LOG FILE EXERPTS:
/* 
    17 Jan 2014 20:10:59 [rsession-bguha] ERROR system error 32 (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) [path=C:/hiberfil.sys]; OCCURRED AT: time_t core::FilePath::lastWriteTime() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:534; LOGGED FROM: time_t core::FilePath::lastWriteTime() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:534
     17 Jan 2014 20:10:59 [rsession-bguha] ERROR system error 32 (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) [path=C:/pagefile.sys]; OCCURRED AT: uintmax_t core::FilePath::size() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:340; LOGGED FROM: uintmax_t core::FilePath::size() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:340

```
17 Jan 2014 19:47:09 [rsession-bguha] CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-bguha): (TypeError) ||| line: 7394||| sourceId: 112341176||| sourceURL: http://127.0.0.1:28933/rstudio/7ABF72ED105B7067B7EBBE5434F51E55.cache.html: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.b.e.Am');|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1 WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Qt/4.8.3 Safari/534.34 Qt/4.8.3

17 Jan 2014 19:35:07 [rsession-bguha] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT: core::Error session::modules::git::::discoverGitBinDir(core::FilePath*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionGit.cpp:2269; LOGGED FROM: void session::modules::git::onUserSettingsChanged() C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionGit.cpp:2493

17 Jan 2014 20:10:59 [rsession-bguha] ERROR system error 32 (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) [path=C:/pagefile.sys]; OCCURRED AT: time_t core::FilePath::lastWriteTime() const :\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:534; LOGGED FROM: time_t core::FilePath::lastWriteTime() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:534; */
```

Comment: This probably belongs as a support request to RStudio, not here.

Comment: Quite and restart RStudio. If that doesn't help try restarting your system.

Comment: Have you tried your script in Rgui or Rterm to exclude that it's not Rstudio?

Comment: @Roman: The first time I tried running in the R-GUI, it crashed in the first attempt; in the second attempt it ran through the 22nd loop and then crashed.

Comment: Then I don't think this is a RStudio issue. It looks to me like the script is the culprit. Without a reproducible example, I'm afraid we will be of little help. For the time being, I'm revoking the rstudio tag.

Comment: I suspect `data.table::fread`, it's notoriously crash-happy. OP, you're just going to have to manually pinpoint the offending command(s) by commenting out lines/setting breakpoints, and rerunning. I've solved similar bugs in the past and that's what I did. I'd suspect fread. Try running up until the fread, then save that context, and restart and run the offending command. Tagging [tag:data.table]